# Weird behavior when using bool as dict key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
python
>>> for k in {True:'a', True:'b'}: print(k)
True
>>> for k in {False:'a', True:'b'}: print(k)
False
True
```

Why isn't the second item displayed in the first case?

Comment: Dicts cannot contain duplicate keys - that second `True` overwrote the first.

Comment: Right! My silly mistake...